# How to use a more accurate DEM in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, geotiff

I want to create a 3D map that is more accurate than the standard one mapbox provides.

I found a DEM of Europe called [EU-DEM](https://land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-dem/eu-dem-v1.1/view) with a vertical accuracy of +/- 7m.
Mapbox only accepts 8-bit GeoTIFFs files but EU-DEM is a 32-Bit DEM. Can this GeoTIFF somehow be converted or are there any other DEMs of central europe out there that would work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with using [gdal](https://gdal.org)? It is easier to convert the tiff, just with a simple command line–[gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html).

Something like this might work for you:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -scale 0 65535 0 255 input.tif output.tif
```